# Why text field is not clearing while value is stored in variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I cannot figure out why that happens. I have an object with method which adds new task to my Todo list from text field value, and after that clears text field. Please see code below:

```
const handlers = {
  addTodo: () => {
    let addTodoTextInput = document.querySelector('#addTodoTextInput'); // returns text field element
    todoList.addTodo(addTodoTextInput.value); // adds task from text field value
    addTodoTextInput.value = ''; // clears text field
  }
};
```

This code works fine, but I tried to store value from text field in variable like that:

```
const handlers = {
  addTodo: () => {
    let addTodoTextInput = document.querySelector('#addTodoTextInput').value; // value from text field stored in variable
    todoList.addTodo(addTodoTextInput); // adds task from text field value, get line above
    addTodoTextInput = ''; // and this does not clear text field
  }
};
```

And in this case text field will be not cleared but if I log variable **addTodoTextInput** to console it is empty. I am curious why that is happening because I was not able to find answer anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: You had it right the first way, you set the `value` attribute of the text input to '', not the text input itself

Comment: please share the HTML code

Comment: What are the datatypes? [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns an `Element` but `.value` is a `String`.  Updating a string isn't going to update the DOM, but updating the `Element` might. It depends on if that element is attached to the DOM, which in this case it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const handlers = {
  addTodo: () => {
    let addTodoTextInput = document.querySelector('#addTodoTextInput').value; // value from text field stored in variable
    todoList.addTodo(addTodoTextInput); // adds task from text field value, get line above
    addTodoTextInput.value = ''; // and this should clear text field
  }
};
```